Why does the VPN client have access to all interfaces instead of being restricted by the subnet and the disable forwarding option?
Context
In my Debian Linux infrastructure, I manage several network interfaces with specific roles.



Interface
Role
Subnet
Description




eth0
Public connection
192.0.2.0/24
Used for external public access.


wg0
WireGuard VPN
10.0.0.0/24
Enables secure communication between machines via the VPN.


vmbr0
Bridge for Proxmox
172.16.0.0/16
Bridge for virtual machines.




Firewall rules: No iptables/nftables rules are currently applied. All chains have a default policy set to ACCEPT.
Kernel configuration: IPv4 forwarding is disabled (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0).


Goal
The goal is to strictly limit network communications in the infrastructure:
When a computer connects to the VPN via the wg0 interface, it should only be able to communicate with a specific virtual machine located on the vmbr0 bridge.
The objective is to ensure complete isolation between interfaces and restrict traffic to this specific use case.

Reproducing the Setup
WireGuard Configuration (fake information)
To replicate the environment, here is a basic WireGuard configuration for two Linux machines:
Machine 1: VPN Server (fake information)
Interface: wg0

Key generation (example keys, generated via wg genkey and wg pubkey):

Private key: 9+9N5R5Dje2dmldDtrjQoBb3AFOWhOAyZ9mfWQKn7QY=
Public key: Ci4z9W+n8gfrFRRGZs3DNMHmKk1TFNG9QXGV7zg5OkE=


WireGuard configuration: (fake information)
File /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 9+9N5R5Dje2dmldDtrjQoBb3AFOWhOAyZ9mfWQKn7QY=
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = YdC5+zMdKj5cRW2WlAv7GDETx+gjZukOmeC+lkJZ8is=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32


Commands to apply:
sudo wg-quick up wg0
sudo systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0



Machine 2: VPN Client (fake information)
Interface: wg0

Key generation:

Private key: mWjXaRlvJjThhf9ZZpaAWwdY0Puvy0k9fGy7prlzvV8=
Public key: YdC5+zMdKj5cRW2WlAv7GDETx+gjZukOmeC+lkJZ8is=


WireGuard configuration:
File /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = mWjXaRlvJjThhf9ZZpaAWwdY0Puvy0k9fGy7prlzvV8=
Address = 10.0.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = Ci4z9W+n8gfrFRRGZs3DNMHmKk1TFNG9QXGV7zg5OkE=
Endpoint = <SERVER_IP>:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/24, 172.16.0.0/16, 192.0.2.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25


Commands to apply:
sudo wg-quick up wg0
sudo systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0



These configurations establish a simple connection between the VPN server (10.0.0.1) and the client (10.0.0.2). This setup forms the basis for testing the described requirement.
Bridge
sudo brctl addbr vmbr0
sudo ip addr add 172.16.0.1/16 dev vmbr0
sudo ip link set dev vmbr0 up

Problem
When a client connects to the VPN via the wg0 interface, the following issues are observed:
Access to all interfaces:
Despite different subnets and IPv4 forwarding being disabled, the VPN client can successfully ping all network interfaces, including eth0 and vmbr0.
Packet visibility:
By running tcpdump on each interface (eth0, vmbr0, and wg0), it is observed that the ping packets only traverse the wg0 interface. However, responses are still received when the client pings other interfaces.
Service exposure:
If a service is running on any interface, such as:
python3 -m http.server --bind 192.0.2.1

(bound to the eth0 IP address 192.0.2.1/24), the VPN client has access to this service.
Interface down scenario:
If an interface (e.g., eth0) is brought down using:
ip link set dev eth0 down

the VPN client can still successfully ping the IP address associated with the downed interface and access the running service (e.g., the HTTP server). This behavior persists regardless of the operational state of the interface.
Restricted VM issue:
When adding a virtual machine on the vmbr0 bridge, the VPN client is unable to ping it. (Normal but why can i ping the bridge)
Request for Assistance
Given the above configuration and observed issues:

Why does the VPN client have access to all interfaces (eth0, vmbr0) instead of being restricted by the subnet and the disable forwarding option ?
How can the VPN client still access services or ping IPs on downed interfaces?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

I rolled back your recent edit, which added "(RESOLVED)" to the title of your question.  Since you have accepted an answer to the issue, the question has already been marked as resolved.


Why does the VPN client have access to all interfaces (eth0, vmbr0) instead of being restricted by the subnet and the disable forwarding option ?

You kind of answered it yourself :)

Packet visibility: By running tcpdump on each interface (eth0, vmbr0, and wg0), it is observed that the ping packets only traverse the wg0 interface. However, responses are still received when the client pings other interfaces.

You don't send an IP packet to an interface, but to a system. Since the IP your are trying to reach is assigned to the system that received the packet, it does not need to forward it to the specific interface the address is configured on. The system handles it locally.
Why ?
ip rule (man 8 ip-rule) would show that the local routing table is the first to be used for processing a packet since it has the lowest priority (0).
From man 8 ip-route:

local - the destinations are assigned to this host. The packets are looped back and delivered locally.

This answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524304/651211) explained it too and gives a solution to prevent such a behavior.

How can the VPN client still access services or ping IPs on downed interfaces?

It depends how is the IPv4 address assigned to the system (and configured on the downed interface). For static addressing, the IPv4 address is still configured on the interface. Just do a quick ip addr show or ip route show table local and see for yourself, the address should still be listed and routed locally.
For IPv6, you decide what to do. The default is to remove the address (see keep_addr_on_down kernel parameter for /proc/sys/net/ipv6/)
