# Prevent Linux from using an IP address on the wrong interface

Tags: linux, networking, security, routing

**Computer A** has two physical interfaces:

- eno0 ⇨ 192.168.1.1/24
- eno1 ⇨ 192.168.2.1/24

**Computer B** has only one physical interface:

- eno0 ⇨ 192.168.2.2/16 (note the abnormally small subnet mask--we'll say that it was set by a malicious user)

Computer A's eno1 is connected to Computer B's eno0 via a dumb switch.

When I run `ping 192.168.1.1` on Computer B, it works! **How can that be?**

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is 0 on both computers.

The iptables FORWARD policy is DROP on both computers and there are no rules in the FORWARD table.

The two computers are not connected to any other networks.

Both computers are running the 6.1.9-arch1-1 kernel.

More to the point: **How can I configure Computer A to prevent this behavior?** I don't want computers on the 192.168.2.0/24 network to be able to access services that are hosted on the 192.168.1.1 address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways to design a TCP/IP stack, known as a *strong host model* and a *weak host model*. It is easier to achieve high performance with the weak host model, and so Linux defaults to it.

Historically, these terms are also known as *strong end system (ES) model* and *weak end system model*, respectively.

The behavior you're looking for (= the system answering for incoming packets only on the specific IP address assigned to the interface the packets came in on) is specific to the *strong host model*, and if you want it, some configuration is needed.

If you [search this site with the keywords "strong host model"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=strong+host+model), you will find a number of questions with detailed answers on how to set this up.

Comment: Thank you! https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411339/54016 had the answer I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not dependent on iptables, forwarding,...

The netmasks, gateways, and routing are the problem here. As you say computer has 16 bit netmask. That means that all computers on networks 192.168.X.X are on his "local" network. Pinging a computer on the network will not go through the gateway but directly to the adapter that is in that network. According to your netmask 192.168.1.1 is on 192.168.2.1 adapter network, so it sends the ping directly to that adapter.

Forwarding would matter, if you received traffic on one adapter and would have to forward it out on another (or the same), but in your case there is no forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

As computer B considers this IP address to be on link given the subnet, it sends an ARP request on that interface.

By default, Linux answers ARP requests for all IP addresses configured on the system regardless of the interface.

If that is not what you want, you need to configure the `net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter` or `net.ipv4.conf.eno1.arp_filter` sysctl entries (documented in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)). Setting it to 1 will restrict arp to addressses on the interface.

If you assume computer B has a static ARP entry for 192.168.1.1 (or has the right subnet and has 192.168.2.1 as gateway) the previous entry won't help. I think you'd need to set up the firewall to block those requests. Since the IP address is owned by computer A, computer A considers those packets to be INPUT and not FORWARD, regardless of the interface they're coming from.