# Linux using wrong default gateway

Tags: arch-linux, routing, networkmanager

I have two internet connections connected over two different network interfaces (ethernet and wifi). The ip addresses configured are 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.2.5 respectively. When I use
`ip route get 8.8.8.8` the system uses the default gateway with the lowest metric (the ethernet route). But when I do `ip route get from 192.168.2.5 8.8.8.8` the system still tries to use the ethernet gateway rather than the wifi gateway:

`8.8.8.8 from 192.168.2.5 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 uid 1000`

Why is this happening?

My routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.10 metric 100
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.5 metric 600
<subnet routes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is set up "source based routing".  Typically routing is destination based.

To do this we need to make use of advanced `ip` functionality, by creating a *second* route table and telling the system when to use that table.

So first add a line to the end of `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` that reads something like

```
100 wifiroute
```

Now you can use this table with the command

```
ip rule add from 192.168.2.5 table wifiroute
```

And finally add a default route to that table

```
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 table wifiroute
```

Of course these two `ip` commands will be lost on reboot so you should ensure they are made part of the boot sequence.

You should now be able to test this, e.g. with `traceroute`

```
traceroute www.google.com
traceroute www.google.com -s 192.168.2.5
```

The second one should go out via wlan0 because we're setting the source address.

You can see the routing table with `ip route show table wifiroute`; you can see all routes from all tables with `ip route show table all`

Answer (score 0):

You can, by definition, have only one working default route. This is the route taken by default (hence its name) for all traffic that doesn't have a specific entry in your routing table.

A route is defined in terms of its destination. You can specify any of the host's IP addresses as the source of the traffic but they will all use the same routing table to decide how to get to the destination.

---

<sup>Actually this isn't strictly true as you can have different namespaces and routing tables, but that's a complexity outside this answer</sup>

Comment: But shouldn't the system try to match the route using the from address specified? If not, why? It makes sense to do so.

Comment: @Aybruh There are two opposing design models for an IP protocol driver: the *strong host model* and the *weak host model*. The former will also note the source address (like you're thinking), the latter will not. The latter can be more efficient, and in cases when the system has just one IP address, the extra checks are useless anyway... and so that is what modern operating systems will tend to use by default. See [this question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258810/258991)